# JOIN three tables + GROUP_CONCAT when there's data + all the rest of the first table

Tags: mysql, sql, string, subquery, aggregate-functions

this might be hard...
three tables

[image: Short DB schema]

I would like to retrieve a list of starship data + crew (group concatenated) + the rest of the starship records without team.

this code is giving back starship with team member one per row...

```
SELECT 
ss.starship_id, ss.starship_name, ss.starship_quota, ss.quota_insert_date as lastupd,
u.nome, u.cognome
FROM starship as ss
    LEFT JOIN user_props as up
    ON ss.starship_id=up.starship_id
    LEFT JOIN users as u
    ON u.id_user=up.id_user
```

this is sample data:

```
id  name        quota   name            surname
------------------------------------------------------
23  HAS CREW    7923    Luke            Skywalker
23  HAS CREW    7923    PAdme            Amidala
------------------------------------------------------
24  UnALTRA       0     Bilbo           Baggins
24  UnALTRA       0     Frodo           Baggins
------------------------------------------------------
22  NO CREW     3552    NULL             NULL


column "lastupd" have been omitted
```

what i would like to have is just a "team" record with concatenated members, or null, when no team is on starship.
see a sample table below:

```
id  name        quota   TEAM
------------------------------------------------------
23  HAS CREW    7923    Luke Skywalker, Padme Amidala
------------------------------------------------------
24  UnALTRA       0         BilBo Baggins, Frodo Baggins
------------------------------------------------------
22  NO CREW     3552    NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a correlated subquery for this:

```
select s.*,
    (
        select group_concat(u.nome, ' ', u.cognome)
        from user_props up
        inner join users u on u.id_user = up.id_user
        where up.starship_id = s.starship_id
    ) team
from starship s
```

Comment: you are missing the surname GROUP_CONCAT(u.nome,' ', u.cognome)